I want the modal window to display an error message before closing
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
const { username, password } = req.body; // Formdan gelen veriyi al

try {
const request = new sql.Request();
const result = await request
  .input("username", sql.VarChar, username) // Kullanıcı adını parametre olarak ver
  .input("password", sql.VarChar, password) // Şifreyi parametre olarak ver
  .query(
    "SELECT * FROM Kullanicilar WHERE kullaniciAdi = @username AND kullaniciSifre = @password"
  ); // Sorgu

if (result.recordset.length > 0) {
  // Kullanıcı bulunduysa giriş başarılı
  console.log("giriş başarılı");
  res.render("user-page");
} else {
  // Kullanıcı bulunamadıysa hata mesajı
  console.log("Geçersiz kullanıcı adı veya şifre");
  res.render("index", {
    errorMessage: "Hatalı kullanıcı adı veya şifre girdiniz.",
  });
}
} catch (err) {
console.error("Giriş işlemi sırasında hata oluştu:", err);
res.status(500).send("Giriş sırasında bir hata oluştu.");
}});
 

<div class="giris gizle">
  <button class="giris-kapat">&times;</button>
  <h1 class="giris-name">Giriş</h1>
  <div>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
      <ul class="giris-list">
        <li class="giris-item">
          <p class="giris-text">Kullanıcı Adı:</p>
          <input type="text" name="username" />
        </li>
        <li class="giris-item">
          <p class="giris-text">Şifre:</p>
          <input type="password" name="password" />
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% if (typeof errorMessage !== 'undefined') { %>
      <p id="error-message" style="color: red; margin-top: 10px">
        <%= errorMessage %>
      </p>
      <% } %>
      <button type="submit" class="giris-btn">Giriş</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

In this code, if the user information is entered incorrectly on the login page in the modal window, I want an error to be returned with red text on the login button before the modal window closes. But now, this code returns an error, but it redirects to the /login page and closes the modal window. I would be happy if you help.

So this currently is just a standard form submission, no client-side JS involved in that part? Then you will have to change that - because a normal form submission will always result in the display of a new page, and therefor your modal, that was part of the current page, can only disappear. You would need to modify this to send the credentials to the server via AJAX/fetch - and then depending on the response, your JS would either show the error message in the modal, or redirect the user to whatever the next page is supposed to be now (probably not the login page any more.)

Add a bootstrap modal into your code. And call it from your catch block.
try { // todo } catch (err) { $('#errorModal').modal('toggle') }


Please add more details on why OP should do this and how does it ties in with the existing implementation.

I click on the login button on my home page and the login modal window appears without any redirects. If the login information is correct, it enters the user's account, if it is incorrect, an incorrect login message is displayed above the button. I want the page to do these without any redirects.
@PrerakSola

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
